# Create Schedule Event throws error when saving

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, heidisql

I will create a schedule Event, that loops all records where the Filed "Online" is "Y" and set this to "N".

For this I have created this Event but when I will save that one, I got the error

> SQL 102: Incorrect syntax newar 'LOGOUT', Incorrect syntax near
>   'CURSOR'

I use HeidiSQL and MS SQL Server 2012

```
    CREATE EVENT "LOGOUT"
    ON SCHEDULE
        EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2019-02-28 00:00:00'
    ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE
    ENABLE
    COMMENT ''
    DO BEGIN
    DECLARE @MyCursor CURSOR;
    DECLARE @MyField VARCHAR;
    BEGIN
        SET @MyCursor = CURSOR FOR
        select Online from dbo.ActiveUser
            where Online = 'Y'      

        OPEN @MyCursor 
        FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor 
        INTO @MyField

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
          Update dbo.ActiveUser Set Online = 'N'
          FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor 
          INTO @MyField 
        END; 

        CLOSE @MyCursor ;
        DEALLOCATE @MyCursor;
    END
END
```

Comment: Did you consider using an SQL Server Agent job for this? Also why are you using a cursor when you can directly update all the records?

Comment: @EzLo  How can I directly update this records?

Comment: `Update dbo.ActiveUser Set Online = 'N' WHERE Online = 'Y'` This will update all records at the same time, no cursor needed.

Comment: You are right, that is much easier, but then I get the error 102 Incorrect syntax near 'logout':  CREATE EVENT "Logout"
 ON SCHEDULE
  EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2019-02-28 11:33:24'
 ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
 ENABLE
 COMMENT ''
 DO BEGIN
Update dbo.ActiveUser Set Online = 'N' WHERE Online = 'Y'
END

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have these type of events, MySQL does. Create a SQL Server Agent Job for this, it's very simple to use. If you are using SSMS and your user has enough privileges, you will see a SQL Server Agent entry on the Object Explorer. Right click on Jobs and New Job.

Comment: OK thanks I will go this way. Thaks for your help and time.